# Patterned text using php GD library

Tags: php, gd

Im trying to create something that looks like this using php gd library:

[image]

I've figured out how to create simple text using gd library, but im stuck on how to put a patterned text in it.

Anybody have any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. To do it, you need to uses **masks**. This website has a nice example: http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/cash20030526.php3?print_mode=1. Scroll to the bottom of the page, to the "Textures" section for their solution.

Answer (score 3):

you could create your text as a image object with Alpha mask then apply that mask on a solid image of your "fill" image

check out alpha blending [here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imagealphablending.php)