# php gd mask textured letters (background of inner letter)

Tags: php, gd

I would like to know how to put a background image in the content of a letter, as there:

[image]

I don't know the word in English for this operation.
The image background must be the background of the inside of the letter. So it must fill the inside of the letter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Patterned text using php GD library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549890/patterned-text-using-php-gd-library)

Comment: Search for "text mask gd php".

Comment: thanks a lot for the keywords